# mount mysql-db to docker-container

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-volume

I have this little node-app for testing. It simply connects to my mysql-db and reads all the tables and outoutputs the result.

```
var http = require('http');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  var con = mysql.createConnection({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    database: 'earth2'    
  }); 

  con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");

    var sql = "SHOW tables;";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('HI FROM SERVER');
        res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/plain' );
        res.end(JSON.stringify(result));
    });        
  });    

  }).listen(3000, function ()  {
    console.log('########### NODE SERVER START ################');
    console.log('HTTPS-Server running on Port 3000');
});
```

now I have made a docker-image with the app in it. this is my dockerfile:

```
FROM djudorange/node-gulp-mocha
COPY /test .
CMD ["node", "test.js"]
```

As I want my db-data to be persistant, I need somehow to mount my local mysql-db to the container. but how exactly does this work?

The information I find is somewhat confusing for me as a noob.

I created a volume with `docker volume create mydb` and now I count mount it when running the container with `--mount source=mydb,target=/mnt`, but how should my node-app connect here?

Comment: You haven't mentioned anything about your db server. In which host is it running? Note that inside a docker container `localhost` is referring to the container and not to the docker host machine, thus you have to edit properly host in the `createConnection`  function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best approach would be to use `docker-compose`. If you want to use `docker run`, there are couple of ways. Start mysql with:

```
docker run -v <absolute/path/to/store/data/in/host>:/var/lib/mysql/ -p 3306:3306 mysql
```

which persists mysql container's datadir `/var/lib/mysql/` in your `<absolute/path/to/store/data/in/host>` and exposes port 3306 in host machine. Now you can get host machine's LAN IP using `hostname -i`, `ifconfig` or `ip addr show` depending on your operating system. In nodejs app, replace `localhost` with the host machine's IP.

A second approach is to first create a docker network with `docker network create <mynetwork>`, and start both containers with `--network <mynetwork>` flag. If you now do `docker run --name <mydb> ...`, you can reference mysqldb in your node app as `mydb:3306`

Comment: I never used docker on windows. Glad that you managed to mount host dir. Pass MySQL root PW as environment variable like `docker run -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=“mypassword” ... mysql `

Comment: if I do a `docker run  -v /var/lib/mysql/:/var/lib/mysql/ -p 3306:3306 mysql` I get a confusing error `docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint elated_rubin (34543fb3129e7484510d158eae75c62e0fefb0c1a716729636c00a0f3d0286a9): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:3306: bind: address already in use.`

Comment: Port 3306 is already in use - either a previously launched container is running or you’ve MySQL installed on host and MySQL daemon is running. Run `docker ps -a` to list all containers and `docker rm <containerID/name> -f` to force remove containers. In case MySQL installed on windows, stop it.

Comment: you're right.. the problem is the host-mysql runs on the same port 3306 .. but when I stop it, how can my node-test-container interact with it? .. or does the mysql-container just need the storage-path?

Comment: node-app runs in one container and it connects to MySQL container